# Disable WordPress' wp_attempt_focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, focus, autofocus

## What I have:

A standard log-in page (specifically, the default WordPress wp-login.php page).

Here are two live examples:

1. https://twentyfourteendemo.wordpress.com/wp-login.php
2. http://demo.opensourcecms.com/wordpress/wp-login.php

## What I need:

I need to disable the auto-focusing of the first textbox in the form.

## What I've tried:

1. I've attempted a hidden or off-screen positioned textbox to steal focus.
2. I've attempted setting the tabindex of all inputs to -1 (very unideal).
3. I've attempted using .blur() on the auto-focused textbox.

None of the approaches work.

Comment: worst case could use setTimeout within ready handler to change focus

Comment: can you change the site? if so, remove wp_attempt_focus function.

Comment: @charlietfl I still can't steal focus using your `setTimeout` suggestion. Code here: http://pastebin.com/2jdrS10g.

Comment: I can and it would work but editing the core files directly isn't a way forward. No hook/filter exists for `wp_attempt_focus` though a hack does: http://www.geeklab.info/2011/04/arrrrgh-kill-it-kill-wp_attempt_focus-with-fire/. It doesn't work for me however. I'm not certain if it's due to the fact that my /wp-login.php is rewritten as /account-login.

Comment: @charlietfl Your solution worked. See answer below.

Comment: @HankLapidez you should not edit the WordPress core files unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those coming from Google, there is now a hook for this in the core (correct from V5.2, could be earlier!).

wp-login.php:1149  enable_login_autofocus : Boolean

```
add_filter('enable_login_autofocus', '__return_false');
```

Will disable the autofocus javascript snippet

Answer (score 1):

I've posted a few solutions on the WordPress SE [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163524/password-field-is-empty-error-when-using-autofill-in-chrome/). Basically there are two ways around it (in WordPress 4.0) that don't involve changing the code itself. Kill the function altogether using a dirty hack:

```
add_action("login_form", "kill_wp_attempt_focus");
function kill_wp_attempt_focus() {
    global $error;
    $error = TRUE;
}
```

Or use [Geeklab's solution](http://www.geeklab.info/2011/04/arrrrgh-kill-it-kill-wp_attempt_focus-with-fire/) to modify the HTML code through buffering, allowing you to specifically kill the autofocus. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution based on charlietfl's setTimeout function.

```
setTimeout(function() {
      $( '<input type="text" id="focusfix" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px;"/>' ).insertBefore( "#loginform #user_login" );
      $('#loginform #focusfix').focus();
      $('#loginform #focusfix').select();
}, 205);
```